# Haskell - State of variables in parsed expression (Is the variable bound or not?)

Tags: parsing, variables, haskell

Hi so I got a function that takes a string and calculates the value, either an int or an bool. The string can be i.e.: "`* let X = 3 in + X 1 2`", which represent "`(let X = 3 in (X + 1)) * 2`". Which will give me 8 or false if I ask for a bool. Simple enough. But I also want to check the state of bound variables in the parser. I.e. if I use a string like this "`* let X = 3 in + X 1 X`" as input, it will represent "`(let X = 3 in (X + 1)) * X`" which makes the last X unbound. This will then give me an error saying that the variable A is unbound or something. 
If someone could give me any ideas on how I could do this, I would be very much appreciated!

*Expample of parsed string:*

`((let X = 3 in (X + 1)) * 2)`

Will give me:

`(Mul (Let (Vari X) (Lit (Single 3)) (Sum (Vari X) (Lit (Single 1)))) (Vari X))`

So my question is basiclly how I can check if the parsed string has any unbound variables.

```
data Number = Single Int | Many Int Number deriving (Eq, Show)

data Expr = Vari Chara | Lit Number | Sub Expr | Sum Expr Expr | Mul Expr Expr | Let Expr Expr Expr | If Expr Expr Expr deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: IMHO this check should happen at a higher level, after parsing.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so, I would at least make it alot easier.

Comment: I think your `Let` constructor is set up incorrectly. The thing on the left hand side of the `=` in `let x = e1 in e2` is a _name_ (or, more generally, a _pattern), not an arbitrary expression. `let (if foo then bar else baz) = x in y` doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurse down the parsed expression, holding a set of bound variables. Every time you come across a `Let`, record it, every time you come across a `Var`, check that it's in your set, and every time you come across something else, check its subexpressions.

```
checkVars' :: Set String -> Expr -> Bool
checkVars' bound (Var v) = S.member v set
checkVars' bound (Let var val expr) = checkVars' bound val && checkVars' (insert var bound) expr
checkVars' bound (Mul expr1 expr2) = checkVars' bound expr1 && checkVars' bound expr2
-- Similar for other ctors...

checkVars :: Expr -> Bool
checkVars = checkVars' S.empty
```

You can also work in the opposite direction, building up a set of free variables from the bottom up, and removing variables whenever you see them bound by `Let`. (This feels more natural.)

```
freeVars :: Expr -> Set String
freeVars (Var v) = S.singleton v
freeVars (Let var val expr) = S.union (freeVars val) $ S.delete var $ freeVars expr
freeVars (Add expr1 expr2) = S.union expr1 expr2
-- etc.

checkVars :: Expr -> Bool
checkVars = S.null . freeVars

-- With recursion-schemes
data ExprF a = Add a a
             | Mul a a
             | Let String a a
             | Var String
             | Lit Int
             deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

type Expr = Fix ExprF

freeVars :: Expr -> Set String
freeVars = cata go -- -XLambdaCase, anyone?
  where go :: ExprF (Set String) -> Set String
        go (Var var) = S.singleton var
        go (Let var val expr) = S.union val $ S.delete var expr
        go e = foldl S.union S.empty e -- Handle everything else
```

Comment: ok, I can't get this to work. I haven't worked with set before, so I kind of don't understand how I am gonna do this. I think I under stands whats going on, but I can't get it to work. (EDIT, I added abit more code in my question)

Comment: @HNTW For what it’s worth I find the top-down traversal more natural. If you’re taking a typed approach, in which scope-checking produces an expression with a locally nameless representation, you need to _rewrite_ the `Var` nodes (to replace them with de Bruijn indices), which is much easier when traversing top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a *locally nameless* representation for variables (such as that provided by [the extraordinarily useful `bound` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound)) in a syntax with binding. In a locally nameless representation, bound variables are represented using de Bruijn indices, and unbound variables are represented using a name. This saves you a whole lot of effort when it comes to things like alpha-equivalence and capture-avoiding substitution, and answering the question "is this variable bound?" becomes very straightforward.

Typically a locally nameless representation is the output of a scope-checking operation on a surface syntax tree. We can adjust the code from [@HNTW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627219/1523776) to produce a checked term instead of a `Bool`:

```
data Scoped a = SVar a
              | SLet (Scoped a) (Scope () Scoped a)  -- The expression being let-bound, and the subexpression with the new variable in scope
              | SLit Number
              | SSub (Scoped a)
              | SSum (Scoped a) (Scoped a)
              | SMul (Scoped a) (Scoped a)
              | SIf (Scoped a) (Scoped a) (Scoped a)
              deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance Applicative Scoped where
    pure = SVar
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Scoped where
    return = SVar
    SVar a >>= g = g a
    SLet expr scope >>= g = SLet (expr >>= g) (scope >>>= g)
    SLit x >>= g = SLit x
    SSub x >>= g = SSub (x >>= g)
    SSum x y >>= g = SSum (x >>= g) (y >>= g)
    SMul x y >>= g = SMul (x >>= g) (y >>= g)
    SIf cond t f >>= g = SIf (cond >>= g) (t >>= g) (f >>= g)

scoped :: Expr -> Scoped Char
scoped (Var x) = SVar x
scoped (Let name expr sub) = SLet (scope expr) (abstract1 name $ scoped sub)
scoped (Lit x) = SLit x
scoped (Sub s) = SSub (scoped s)
scoped (Sum x y) = SSum (scoped x) (scoped y)
scoped (Mul x y) = SMul (scoped x) (scoped y)
scoped (If cond t f) = SIf (scoped cond) (scoped t) (scoped f)
```

`bound` views an expression as a "container" of names `a`. The `Monad` instance performs substitution (`(>>=) :: Scoped a -> (a -> Scoped b) -> Scoped b` takes a function mapping names `a` to terms `Scoped b` and grafts them together), and the `bound` library makes use of this substitution operation to implement tools like [`abstract1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-2.0.1/docs/Bound.html#v:abstract1), which binds a variable in a subexpression, producing a new subexpression in a locally nameless form.

(It wouldn't be unreasonable to do away with the separate `Expr` type, and just produce a `Scoped Char` directly as the output of your parser.)

`Scoped`'s `Foldable` and `Traversable` instances let you find all the unbound variables in an expression.

```
unboundVariables :: Scoped a -> [a]
unboundVariables = toList
```

`bound`'s [`isClosed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-2.0.1/docs/Bound.html#v:isClosed) combinator does just what you wanted: it returns `False` if the expression has any free variables.

If, as you walk under a scope, you need to know if a particular variable is bound or free, you can either pattern-match on [`Var`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-2.0.1/docs/Bound.html#t:Var)'s `B` and `F` constructors, or use [the supplied `Prism`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-2.0.1/docs/Bound-Var.html#v:_B):

```
isBound :: Var b f -> Bool
isBound = is _B
```

For more on how `bound` works, see [this blog post](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/bound) or [these slides](https://www.slideshare.net/ekmett/bound-making-de-bruijn-succ-less).